# c# property override Set method

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class like the below, I want to override the set value of "School,Country..etc.." property when some one sets a value , i don't want to change the student class but i need to do it in the base class and use it as a generic method

```
public class Student : BaseClass
{
       public String School { get; set; }
       public String Country{ get; set; }
}
```

ie:
When some one sets
`Student.School="Harvard"`, 
I need to store it as
`Student.School="Harvard my custom value"`;

Note: 
Basically calling OnPropertyChanged in **base class** rather than the main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with aspects, then try [Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/download)

Comment: I think that's not free, i need to purchase it   :-)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot override a non-virtual property. You can hide it by other property with the same name in the derived class, but this won't give you the desired effect if some other code accesses your object by the reference to the base class.

Comment: Can it be done by Aspect oriented programming Model like [MyCustomAttribute]  public String School{get;set;};

Comment: Don't know, but if yes, this surely requires some code on the `BaseClass`'s side.

Comment: yes i agree, some work has to be done on base class. but how to do it..?

Comment: What is the problem if you can modify the base class?

Comment: i have not yet modified the base class, looking for ways to modify it

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Student : BaseClass
{
    private string _school
    public string School 
    {
        get { return _school; }
        set
        {
            if(value == "Harvard")
                value = "Harvard custom";

            _school = value;
        }
    }

    public String Country{ get; set; }
}
```

is that what you mean?

If the `School` property is in the `BaseClass` then you can either use the `new` keyword, or if you control the `BaseClass`, then you can add the `virtual` keyword to the `School` property there, and `override` it in the `Student` class.

Comment: But i don't want to do it in Student class, i want to have it in BaseClass because i have 100's of property in several classes.. i want to append common value to the end of it.

Comment: then do it in the base class, I don't understand what's your problem here. you want to be able to change that value? use an event or a delegate, or call a virtual function on the property setter in BaseClass and then override it in the Student class

Comment: my point is  i don't want the pain of writing  set
        {
            if(value == "Harvard")
                value = "Harvard custom";

            _school = value;
        }
in every property, somehow i need to do it automatically..

Comment: consider custom value is a Time (minute and Second)..i don't want to write the code on every property

Comment: so you want to add something like the last modification date on each individual property in your class?

Comment: originally i want to invoke "OnPropertyChanged" method without writing it in every properties set value (but iam ok with having it as attribute)

Answer (score 0):

This is just not doable by solely modifying `BaseClass`. Think about it this way: If it were possible to "annotate" automatic properties that easily, then we wouldn't need all those <rant>useless tons of</rant> manual property implementations for data model classes that implement INotifyPropertyChanged (same for DependencyProperties).

You need to provide hooks in your subclasses that your base class can use. Implementing PropertyChanged, which you already mentioned, is one possible solution, another one would be a simple method call:

```
public class Student : BaseClass
{
   private string _school;
   public String School 
   {
       get { return _school; }
       set {
            _school = value;
            DoMoreChanges(ref _school);  // DoMoreChanges is defined in BaseClass
       }
   }

   public String Country{ get; set; }
}
```

If you have lots of subclasses that need this, you can either use Visual Studio Code Snippets to create the code or [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Since your base class does not have those properties you will not be able to modify them from within the base class using standard OOD patterns or principles.

Now if you move the properties to your base class either as normal properties or virtual properties you can modify what you do in the set block of the properties to do extra work.

However if you cannot move these to the base class, and you cannot modify the Student class, as you seem to imply in you question, then you could encapsulate the student class within a new class like StudentProxy or something and then have it expose similar properties that will then call into the real student class how you want.

For example:

```
public class StudentProxy
{
    private Student _student;

    public StudentProxy(Student student)
    {
        this._student = student;
    }

    public String School
    {
        get { return _student.School; }
        set
        {
            _student.School = value + "  my custom value";
        }
    }

    public String Country
    {
        get { return _student.Country; }
        set
        {
            _student.Country = value + "  my custom value";
        }
    }
}
```